# Tweepy is slow for big twitter accounts

Tags: python, asynchronous, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm making a twitter monitor with tweepy, where every second, it gets the lastest 2 tweets from an account through user_timeline(user, count=2), and if they're new tweets, it sends a discord notification.

It all worked perfectly well with a small account like mine, where I only have a couple of tweets in it. It had a delay of as little as 0.5 seconds since the tweet was created. Now I'm testing with bigger accounts with for example, more than a total amount of 1000 tweets created. Now the delay is as little as 2 seconds and up to 30 seconds.

Do you know why this may be? Is there some other more efficient way of doing this same task? I first thought it was because it was fetching the latest 200 tweets by default, but I changed that by adding "count=2" to the user_timeline function and the delay is still the same.

PD:
I use app-only authentication and this is part of my code:

```
async def monitor_user(self, api, username, last_updated):
    data = []

    try:
        fut = self.client.loop.run_in_executor(
            None, lambda: api.user_timeline(username, count=2)
        )
        await fut
        tweets = fut.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the streaming endpoint:
http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html

With that you can follow 5000 twitter users, track 400 keywords and implement 25 location boxes:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter

New status that get posted arrive in under 2 seconds and it is a lot faster than querying individual twitter accounts. The rate limit for the user_timeline endpoint is 180 query calls every 15 minutes. This means the more people you want to track the less frequently you are allowed to check meaning there will be a significant delay.

The downside of the streaming endpoint is it will only show newly posted statuses.